# Get Laravel variable from DB to apline.js

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have HTML in Database and parse it with alpine.js to view that is working correctly but when I try add Laravel variable only see variable name:

```
Shop name: {!! $user->shopName !!}
```

Instead:

```
Shop name: test
```

When parse from controller it's ok in Alpine use

```
html: `{!! html_entity_decode($user) !!}`
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Could you share a little bit more context? Currently there's not a single line of Alpine.js code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this inside blade -

```
Shop name: {{ $user->shopName }}
```

It'd print the data.

Comment: Same not working

Comment: Provide more details. What is your expected output? Attach a screenshot if possible.

Comment: In blade variable I have HTML with other blade variable